# How can i fix 'npx react-native run-android' error? use 'npx react-native run-android' command and get this error:

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-native

```
 PS E:\reactNative\AwesomeProject> npx react-native run-android
    info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
    Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
    info JS server already running.
    info Installing the app...
    Could not unzip C:\Users\Hp\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.5-all\byeise1led9a3w3p149d02kfj\gradle-5.5-all.zip to C:\Users\Hp\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.5-all\byeise1led9a3w3p149d02kfj.
    Reason: error in opening zip file
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:219)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
```

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081        
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:219)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:219)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:75)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (E:\reactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (E:\reactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:179:41)
    at E:\reactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:133:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (E:\reactNative\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:182:9)
PS E:\reactNative\AwesomeProject>
```

Comment: Close all running workers and remove android/app/build folder and try again

Answer (score 0):

You have to **delete gradle gradle-5.5-all.zip** file in the folder located at C:\Users\Hp.gradle\wrapper\dists on you computer.

You can also clean you project using command "**gradlew clean**" on android folder. This is optional but i will recommend it.

Then run "**npx react-native run-android**" and also make sure you are connected to internet since it will download files over internet